# Is registered ram the same as ECC ram?

Tags: memory, ecc

> Registered (often referred to as "buffered") memory uses a technology that is often paired with, but not directly related to, ECC RAM. Registered memory has a "register" that resides between the RAM and the system's memory controller which lessens the load that is placed on the memory controller itself. This allows for more memory modules to be used at one time than would otherwise be possible.

That doesnt tell me if they're both achieving the same thing

Comment: No. It is not the same thing. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_memory, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory

Comment: From your quote "is often paired with, but not directly related to, ECC RAM"

Answer (score 3):

No.

ECC Ram has extra memory modules in it configured to provide error correction for single bit flips, and notify against more then 2 bit flips.   This makes it more reliable and more expensive then normal memory.  (Bit flips can indicate faulty memory, but can also very occasionally be due to cosmic radiation)

Registered memory is a mechanism for optimizing memory transfer to the computer by adding additional circuitry

Answer (score 1):

Absolutelly not!

ECC RAM - Error correction code memory (ECC memory), is a type of computer data storage that **uses an error correction code** (ECC) to detect and correct n-bit data corruption which occurs in memory.
Advantages: Same speed as Standard RAM and Better Memory error correctiom.
Disadvantage: More expensive than Standard RAM

Registered RAM (or Buffered RAM) uses a **buffer register between the CPU and the Memory Module Cells**.
Advantages: The Processor can acces more than it should have been possible
Disadvantages: More expensive than Standard RAM and is a bit slower.

ECC RAM is mostly used in SERVERS, where Data High Speed and Data Authenticity are crucial.

Registered RAM is also mostly used in servers, where the CPU needs to acces more RAM than the number of address lines it has. **Registered RAM doubles the amount of RAM the CPU can access!**

There are also combinations of the above:
ECC RAM + Registered

Rule of thumb for usage in servers:

- If the server has enough address lines, for the desired amount of memory then buy ECC RAM
- If the server can only access 512GB RAM but you need 1TB RAM then use Registered RAM (and live with the speed penalty).

Obviously one can buy ECC RAM without been Registered(Buffered) but I don't think you can buy Buffered RAM which is not Registered.